# Test CDN link from function.php or wp_enqueue_script/style?

Tags: functions, theme-development, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

How can I check if CDN link is alive from function.php file on wp_enqueue section?

E.g.
I have jQuery CDN and I have downloaded jQuery on local.

How can I test before mount theme (WordPress site) is CDN alive, if it is not, enqueue my local file?

Maybe test headers from request and status code?

```
$ch = curl_init('https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js');
curl_exec($ch);


if (!curl_errno($ch)) {
  switch ($http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE)) {
    case 304:
    case 200:  # OK
      wp_register_script ( 'latest-jquery', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js' );
      break;
    default:
      wp_register_script ( 'latest-jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-3.5.0.min.js.js' );
  }
}


curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: You can't, and you shouldn't. More importantly, you should not deregister jQuery and insert your own, especially at a different version to core. This can and does cause problems with plugins and themes, and is very bad practice. Doing this would also mean your site can only be as fast as the request to fetch jQuery at the server end and never faster, it's a huge performance/speed penalty, nevermind the hit to SEO. I strongly advise against even attempting this

Comment: Thanks! It was my goal to secure my core files and relieve server and site.